# Undefined variable: subjects (View: B:\laravel2\forum\resources\views\home.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

i've tried my best but i still dont understand,i try to call the $subject from view to controller but my web always show this error message

here's my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Forum;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\subjects;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ThreadController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('Auth');
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $subjects = Subjects::all();
        return view("threads.create", ['subjects' -> $subjects]);
    }
}
```

here's my blade template

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
        <select  name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control">
            <option name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control">
            </option>
            @foreach ($subjects as $subject)
                <option value="{{ $subject->id }}">{{ $subject->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
```

and this is the error messages

ErrorException

> Undefined variable: subjects (View: B:\laravel2\forum\resources\views\home.blade.php)

Comment: return view("threads.create",compact('subjects'));

Comment: I'm surprised you're not getting other errors. You're using the wrong arrow type. `'subjects' -> $subjects` should be `'subjects' => $subjects`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    return view("threads.create", ['subjects' -> $subjects]);
```

Must be converted to

```
    return view("threads.create", ['subjects' => $subjects]);
```

Or you can use the php function *compact*.

`return view("threads.create",compact('subjects');`